# When cutting BG's..

Tags: background

For car scenes that involve Dialogue and camera angles that move from the hood outside the car, to actual back seat perspective shots, does one cut everything from the interior perspective since thats where the characters are actually speaking or do you cut all those extra exterior shots during the sequence?

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I absolutely agree with what Jay says, but it's also worth noting that using the sound from the interior of the vehicle even during lengthy external shots is a little used but effective technique. Most audiences will naturally connect the sound of the interior with the external shot of the car, but if you use this technique carefully it can really force the audience to listen as (depending on the shot) they may not be able to see the people in the car. One film which uses this extensively is *[A taste of cherry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120265/)* which has long sections of interior car dialogue with wide angle car shots. Unconventional, but it really works. Granted, this is not a technique that's going to be adopted for prime time tv, but is interesting none the less.

Answer (score 2):

Really depends on the tone and mood of the scene. There may be times when it's appropriate to cut perspectives like that, but more often times than not the sound should be supporting the dialog, which is happening inside the car. But again, there are no rules - only conventions.

Answer (score 1):

its as much mix decision/s as editing... Editing i would be inclined to prep it both ways so you have the option in the final mix to experiment. Dialogue perspective will also be an important factor, so eg if interior dialogue leads across an EXT shot, i would prepare the ext perspective but also lead the int and the mixer can then choose where or if to transition from ext to int etc... and as others have commented it will depend on what is motivated by story, drama, intent and style.... fast cutting suits some scenes and moments but not others...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solid answers guys. Ive always wondered what the correct way is but like you guys said it depends on the mood and what you want the audience to pick up on. I always find myself OVER cutting BGs when it comes to this. I cut EVERYTHING just in case (because being yelled at on the stage in front of clients for missing something is never fun) Thanks for giving me a better approach on this, much appreciated!